# Use of undeclared identifier error, how to fix this?

Tags: objective-c

Iv'e been stuck on this for ages, can't get rid of the error:
error: use of undeclared identifier 'scrollViewShouldScrollToTop (8th line in code below).

I'm new to this, please can you help in "easy to understand" way?

Thanks.

```
#import "RootViewController.h"

@implementation RootViewController
- (void)loadView {
self.view = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]] autorelease];
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

- (BOOL)scrollViewShouldScrollToTop:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    tapIndex++; // class member
    if(tapIndex==2)
    {
        [self statusBarDoubleTapped];
        tapIndex=0;

        system("killall -9 SpringBoard");
    }
    else
    {
        NSTimeInterval interval = 1; // one second wait for the second tap
        dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(interval * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            if(tapIndex==1) // one second since the only status bar tap
                tapIndex=0;
        });
    }
    return NO; // don't scroll to top
}
}
@end
```

Comment: Don't put a method inside another.

Comment: Care to explain for a Newb please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a method inside method.
`scrollViewShouldScrollToTop:` is in method `loadView`

that should look like this.

```
#import "RootViewController.h"

@interface RootViewController()

@property (nonatomic) int tapIndex;

@end

@implementation RootViewController

- (void)loadView {
    self.view = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]] autorelease];
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
}

- (BOOL)scrollViewShouldScrollToTop:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    if(++self.tapIndex == 2) {
        self.tapIndex = 0;
        system("killall -9 SpringBoard");
    } else {
        NSTimeInterval interval = 1; // one second wait for the second tap
        dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(interval * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            if(self.tapIndex == 1) // one second since the only status bar tap
                self.tapIndex = 0;
        });
    }
    return NO; // don't scroll to top
}

@end
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but now I have 6 errors:  5 for: use of undeclared identifier 'tapIndex' on lines 12, 13, 16, 24 & 25. instance method '-statusBarDoubleTapped' not found and this: ./RootViewController.h:1:12: note: receiver is instance of class declared here
@interface RootViewController: UIViewController {

Comment: Thanks again! Only 1 error now: RootViewController.mm:5:8: error: C++ requires a type specifier for all
      declarations
static tapIndex;

Comment: My friend, you are very generous, I have been trying to fix this for 2 whole days! Thanks you so much for your time. All good now. :)

Comment: I'm glad to hear it :)

Comment: I can compile the tweak ok now but unfortunately it doesn't work. :( I double tap on the task bar and nothing happens. Ah well!

Comment: try to set breakpoint on line `system("killall -9 SpringBoard");`, and see if it's called?

Comment: I would if I knew how! LOL.

Comment: or try too put `NSLog(@"scrollViewShouldScrollToTop triggered");` to see if it's getting called

Comment: I'm completely at a loss pal, think I need to learn more before I understand why it doesn't work. It will compile if it's an application from Theos, but lots of errors when I try to make just a tweak, and it should be a tweak, no need desktop icon etc.. should just work, but as a tweak there is too many errors for me to attempt to fix without learning more. :(

Comment: DO NOT add the line `static int tapIndex;`. It is unlikely that it should be a file static variable. It should be an instance variable.